# How to find location between two points A and B in google maps with Python

Tags: python, google-maps

I want to find if a location lies on a route between A and B. I see that we 
can do that in JavaScript using containsLocations() and isLocationOnEdge().
But how can we use this with python? Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything yet or you are yet to start and need help with starting?

Google has client libraries for Python 
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Part of which are documentation, and in that documentation you find that when using a client library what you essentially get is way to make requests to the Google Maps API (and its subsets)

Here you need the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Pass in the value for the `origin` and `destination` parameters, and of course the API key, then use the client library to make requests. Use the returned data to your benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Deepak. I tried to install googlemaps api and found the route directions between two places A,B. Now i need to figure out the way to find whether a given lat and long exists between the driving path A -> B.

Comment: I don't think you can get help on concepts that you have not tried for yourself. For that new problem, post a new question SO, provide the code that you have tried, and explain what doesn't seem to be working, if you face any issue that the docs doesn't seem to be explaining.